# No data in php $_POST: Using jQuery + ajax + serialize and Form

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, post

**HTML**

```
    <div id="searchDIV">
    <div id="searchFormDIV">
        <form name="searchFORM" onSubmit="processSearch();" action="" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr id="searchFormHDRs">
                    <td>Manuf / Groups</td><td>Search</td><td>Options</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="manuf" type="radio" value="All" onclick="searchResetListDIV('#searchListDIV')" checked="YES">All
                        <input name="manuf" type="radio" value="Choose" onclick="showDIV('#searchListDIV')">Choose
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="searchBOX">
                        <input type="submit" name="SearchSubmit" value="Search">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="booleans" type="radio" value="and" checked="YES">and&nbsp;
                        <input name="booleans" type="radio" value="or">or&nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>  <!-- end of searchFormDIV -->
</div>  <!-- end of searchDIV -->
```

**PHP**

```
echo '<h3 style="margin:5px;">POST Variables</h3>';
print_r($_POST);
```

**Javascript**

```
            function processSearch(){
            //alert('Doing Search');
            $.ajax({
                url: "WCITSearch.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#searchFORM').serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert("SUCCESS from PHP:");
                    dispJSON(data);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("XMLHttpRequest="+XMLHttpRequest.responseText+"\ntextStatus="+textStatus+"\nerrorThrown="+errorThrown);
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        }
```

Help - I am obviously doing something stupid, but I can not see what.  My processSearch() is being executed, the PHP is run, but no form variables appear to be in $_POST.

I am trying to retrieve $_POST['searchBOX'], but it says invalid index

Thanks

mcl

Comment: Include your Javascript code that actually sends the data to the PHP script; I'm guessing you're doing a `GET` request instead of a `POST` request.

Comment: I have done `print_r` on both `$_POST` and `$_GET` and both are empty

Comment: SOLVED IT.  The form only had Name= and not ID=.  Silly me and thanks to those who made suggestions.